# custom server with next js + node js + express

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I am trying to setup Next JS project along with node server and express. Following are the steps I followed to create project.

1. Create next JS app with below command

   **npx create-next-app@latest test-next-app**

   This will auto install project with dependencies
2. I wanted to create custom server so i created file called server.js and added below code

```js
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");
const path = require("path");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev, dir: path.join(__dirname, ".next") });
app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  // Define custom routes or server logic here

  //   server.get("*", (req, res) => {
  //     return app.render(req, res, "/custom", req.query);
  //   });

  server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:3000");
  });
});
```

3. After server file is created, I modified my package.json like below

```js
{
  "name": "next-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "server.js", 
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "13.5.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.5.6"
  }
}
```

4. After modifying I created build with below command

   **npm run build**

   This will create minified version of next app with folder .Next.
5. Copied my build to server and trying to run app manually with below command
   **node server.js**

This is giving following error "> Couldn't find any `pages` or `app` directory. Please create one under the project root". I am not able to understand what am I missing in this flow.

Answer (score -1):

I duplicated your code above, and made some adjustments:

```
const next  = require('next');
const nextBuild = require('next/dist/build').default
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')

const server = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

const start = async () => {
    if (process.env.NEXT_BUILD) {
        server.listen(PORT, async () => {
            console.log(`Next.js is now building...`)
            // @ts-expect-error
            await nextBuild(path.join(__dirname, '..'))
            process.exit()
        })

        return
    }

    const app = next({
        dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    })

    // these next two lines are what you're missing for handling next HTTP requests
    const nextHandler = app.getRequestHandler()
    server.use((req, res) => nextHandler(req, res))

    app.prepare().then(() => {
        console.log('Next.js started')

        server.listen(PORT, async () => {
            console.log(`Next.js App URL: ${process.env.NEXT_SERVER_URL}`)
        })
    })
}

start()
```

Afterwards ran:

`yarn build && yarn serve`